# Positioning Stacked NSTextView subviews within Scroll View

Tags: objective-c, nstextview, nsscrollview, subviews

This might be a long winded explanation but I'd rather say too much than not enough. In a nutshell I need to embed a series of stacked textViews in a single scrollView programatically and I can't get it working. I'm basing my efforts off the Text Architecture sample code in the docs.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/TextFonts/Conceptual/CocoaTextArchitecture/TextSystemArchitecture/ArchitectureOverview.html

I can create a textView programatically well enough but I can't make two inside a scroll view and have them move as one and be editable. There's a nice little diagram explaining how it's possible to create pagination using the same basic concepts but there is no accompanying code and I haven't been successful at doing it myself. I've made a sad little collage of overlapping textViews where only one is editable so far.

Also, if there is a standard way of accomplishing this, a nudge in the right direction would be most appreciated.

Here's my code:

```
float w = self.windowView.frame.size.width;
float h = self.windowView.frame.size.height*.5;
NSSize halfSize = NSMakeSize(w,h);


textStorage = [[NSTextStorage alloc]
               initWithString:@"Here's to the ones who see things different."];
NSLayoutManager *layoutManager;
layoutManager = [[NSLayoutManager alloc] init];
[textStorage addLayoutManager:layoutManager];
NSTextContainer *textContainer;
textContainer = [[NSTextContainer alloc]
                 initWithContainerSize:halfSize];
[layoutManager addTextContainer:textContainer];

NSTextContainer *textContainer2;
textContainer2 = [[NSTextContainer alloc]
                 initWithContainerSize:halfSize];
[layoutManager addTextContainer:textContainer2];


self.windowView = [[NSTextView alloc]
            initWithFrame:_windowView.frame
            textContainer:textContainer];

[self.window setContentView:_windowView];
[self.window makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
[self.window makeFirstResponder:_windowView];

NSTextView *textView = [[NSTextView alloc]init];
    [textView setTextContainer:textContainer2];

[self.windowView addSubview:textView];
[textView setFrameSize:halfSize];
NSPoint thePoint = NSMakePoint(0, self.windowView.frame.size.height);
[textView setFrameOrigin:thePoint];
[textView setEditable:YES];
[textView setNeedsDisplay:YES];
```

I should mention. I'm an enthusiast, but by no means a particularly competent programmer. Completely self taught. (Well, actually the book I bought did most of the teaching). I just finished Hillegrass's Cocoa Programming for Mac OSX and I'm working on a bit of a personal learning project to get the ball rolling.  I want to make a screenwriting app which formats scene headings, descriptions, dialogs, characters, etc in different ways and 
attaches a bunch of information to each section so that standing over a block would show information about that particular segment (scene info).

I've been making mini apps to test everything I would need and so far I've gone through the Text Attribute Guide and The Text Layout Guide in the docs and have figured out a lot. I'm using Core data and bindings for most of everything but I'm stuck at what is arguably the most important part of the app. Getting the main scrollView to display stacked blocks of differently styled text that can be accessed individually by other parts of the app. (my thoughts are on creating an array of NSTextViews and using current index to link an array of info items to particular blocks, though I keep thinking this feels like a bindings sort of job.)

Thanks in advance!

- Omar